# Html Color Code Pickup in javascript

Tags: javascript

Actually i want that, suppose i have a colorcode #FF3366. How can i examine that it is lighter or darker?
Actually i want to create a textfield and when the font color of the textfield is changed to lighter color by a javascript then the background color of the textfield becomes darker autometically for showing the value of the text field clearly and vise versa.

Please help me.

Comment: Please provide what have you done so far. We can help with advice but we can't do it all for you.

Comment: This isn't a place where we just hand out code. We help you when you run into issues with code you're writing. Try searching Google for if you want code. Maybe the "difference" between two colors can tell you if one is lighter/darker than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula is from years ago, in the W3's site, but I can't locate the address. 
It sorts rgb colors from darkest to lightest. Works fine with just 2...

```
function lumenSort(ac, bc){
    return ((ac[0]*299 + ac[1]*587 + ac[2]*114)/1000-
    (bc[0]*299 + bc[1]*587 + bc[2]*114)/1000);
}
var A= [[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255]].sort(lumenSort);
alert(A[0]+' is darker than '+A[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you can use the API exposed by [COLOURlovers](http://www.colourlovers.com/api) to do what you need. Personally I haven't used the service before nor am I affiliated with it any way but rather was the first result from Google.

Comment: Actually i want that, suppose i have a colorcode #FF3366. How can i examine that it is lighter or darker?

Comment: The way you just [keep copying and pasting the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077764/cookie-can-not-accessed/11077805#comment14502845_11077805) makes it seem as if you either don't understand the question or are incapable of understanding the answer. You certainly have no respect for the people you are asking to help you