# Cookie can not accessed

Tags: php

I am facing a another problem. I built a project in php. the url is like 'www.mysite.com'
I create a cookie using `setcookie()` method in example1.php page which is under root directory and the path of the page is ... `www.mysite.com/in/example1.php`

Now i want to retrieve the value of the cookie in the page 'indix.php' whose url is `www.mysite.com/index.php` that is outside the folder 'in'.

But the cookie is not found in this `index.php` page.
i use `print_r()` but no cookie found.

What the wrong i have done? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Scope of cookie is 4th variable (the "path") - defaults to current path. Sounds like you need to set it to server root directory, or '/'.

```
setcookie('mycookie', 'myvalue', 0, '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the cookie

```
setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

you have to set the `$path` parameter to '/' this way it will be visible everywhere in your page. Also check your `$expire` parameter.